# What is the difference between "system32\java.exe" and "Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe"?

Tags: environment-variables, java

I have just installed Java JDK 6u33 in Windows XP. Even though I didn't set the PATH environment variable, I am able to run `java -version` in command prompt.

When I run this command `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i`, I get this output:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe`

When I check my PC, I found that there are 2 java.exe:
1. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe`
2. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe`

May I know what is the difference between `system32\java.exe` and `Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe`? Why only `system32\java.exe` is shown when I run `for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i`?

Do I still need to add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\` to my PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Setting the `PATH`variable is just so that you can get access to `javac` and the other programs and tools in the jdk bin folder.

The `java.exe` in `\windows\system32\` is provided so that not everyone needs to set a PATH variable just to run a java program (from the command line) **and** selects a version (the last one installed it seems) of the installed java virtual machines (JVM) if there are more than one (publicly) installed.

See this link for further info:

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#MULTIPLES

Quote:

> To complicate things further the java.exe in system32 is just a dummy.
>   It looks in the registry and then decides which real java.exe to use.
>   The last JVM installed gets to be the one used, even if it is older.
>   To switch JVM s, you must normally reinstall the one you want.

Comment: It 's not a dummy "java.exe" and you don't need to reinstall, you simple pass the required version with the -version parameter like `java -version:"1.6" MyClass` to force the 1.6 JRE on a workstation with muliple version installed (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: True that you can bypass the need for a reinstall of course *if* you pass it command line parameters, and you can also of course specify the full path to the java runtime instead (java.exe, javaw.exe or javaws.exe). Neither is very "auto magic" for most users though.

Answer (score 12):

(Not an answer but rather a comment on Mattias's answer)
Not sure about this "dummy" business.  The java.exe in system32 is a normal file, not even a symbolic or hard link.  Mattias may be referring to the problem that is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187

In a nutshell, if you have a 64-bit system and a Java installation, 32-bit applications won't see the java.exe (nor javaw.exe, javaws.exe) that is installed in C:\Windows\System32\ because they'll be presented with C:\Windows\SysWoW64\ masquerading as C:\Windows\System32. The installer fails to put a copy of java.exe in SysWoW64, hence a 32-bit app that tries to launch Java will fail to do so.  This will puzzle the user if he looks in the system32 directory using explorer, since explorer is a 64-bit app and will thus see the "real" system32 directory.

Comment: On a 64-bit system, you typically should install both the 64-bit and the 32-bit versions of Java.

Comment: I have such installation, but for example 64bit Eclipse runs 32bit Java, any idea why? When I run `java -version` it returns 32 bit version also. Is it possible to modify  it to use 64bit primarily?

Comment: Betlista, do you have both JDKs installed?

Comment: Check the task manager, if it says `eclipse.exe *32` then you have a 32-bit Eclipse, which will use 32-bit Java. To use 64-bit Java you need a 64-bit Eclipse.

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32 bit program so it will have problem to see the 64 bit Java under System32/