# jetty: error 500 A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, jetty

I really need help.

I'm trying to run my jsp aplication on new machine and jetty gives me this error:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

I'm using ecplipse kepler, maven and win8.1 x64.

I know there was a lot of these questions but I'va tried everything:
-reinstall jdk and jre;
-add a java directory in eclipse.ini by -vm
-home path is workin - I can call java from command line

all of these not fix my problem...

EDIT: problem solved - it was eclipse luna bug - in eclipse kepler it is working

Comment: How do you invoke jetty?

Comment: by maven build and goals jetty:run

Comment: Inside Eclipse?  Then change the JVM chosen in the launch configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Jetty needs a JDK to compile the JSP files, not just a JRE. Your JAVA_HOME enviroment variable (or the one in the Jetty config) is probably pointing to the JRE instead of the JDK version.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing:

jetty.xml  in C:\Program Files\jetty-distribution-9.2.19.v20160908\etc

Add:

```
<call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
    <arg>org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199</arg>
    <arg>true</arg>
</call>
```

under "configure" element

Answer (score 0):

for my case only ... i don't know if it really answer your question

make sure that invoking `java` is from JDK path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xx\bin`

i just reinstall new JDK. JDK installation put `java.exe` in the path `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`

even if i config PATH variable correctly i will still be invoking from `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`

because it overrides calling from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xx\bin\`

so i will get that same error if i run

```
java -cp jetty-runner-9.2.13.v20150730.jar org.eclipse.jetty.runner.Runner xxx.war
```

i know it might sounds stupid but my solution is to delete `C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe`

read more here [“system32\java.exe” and “Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063831/what-is-the-difference-between-system32-java-exe-and-program-files-java-jdk1)

Answer (score -1):

```
properties->Libraries->JRE System Library->Edit->Installed JREs->Edit->JRE home
```

[image]