# Why those 4 files will copy to Windows/System32 folder when install the new JDK?

Tags: java

Why those 4 files will copy to Windows/System32 folder when install the new JDK?

[image]

Comment: Probably that they will be found through existing PATH (system variable) entries and therefore can be used without explicitly specifying the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do this to get around problems when the Java executable path is not set in the %Path% environment variable.

Read more here: [What is the difference between "system32\java.exe" and "Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063831/what-is-the-difference-between-system32-java-exe-and-program-files-java-jdk1)

Comment: Good comment than the answer.

Comment: yes, thanks. but this will cause some unreasonable problem when run the java application for a developer in the develop environment.

Comment: @Leo Huang why will this cause problems ?