# What does "2^>^&1" mean in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm just learning batch script. I'm reviewing the [getJavaVersion.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/Java/getJavaVersion.bat) script on GitHub. I understood what the `2^>^&1` expression in the following line of code is used for. But I couldn't understand how this syntax (`2^>^&1`) is used. Can you help me with this?

```
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
```

The commands below show the generated values:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('java -fullversion') do set output=%%i
echo %output%
:: OUTPUT >> java full version "18.0.1.1+2-6"

for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
echo %jver%
:: OUTPUT >> 18011+2
```

Comment: Please read about [escape characters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) and about [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.htmlI).

Comment: `java -version` or `java -fullversion` returns the output in the _STDERR_ stream (handle `2`) rather than in the _STDOUT_ stream (handle `1`). `for /F`, together with a command behind the `in` keyword, captures and parses the command output at the _STDOUT_ stream. To capture the _STDERR_ stream you need to redirect it by `2>&1`, meaning that handle `2` (_STDERR_) is redirected where handle `1` points to (_STDOUT_). To ensure that the redirection is not applied to the `for /F` command itself, you need to properly escape it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command [`java -version` or `java -fullversion`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28749535) returns the [output at the *STDERR* stream (handle `2`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13483443) rather than at the *STDOUT* stream (handle `1`). [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), together with a command behind the `in` keyword, captures and parses the command output at the *STDOUT* stream. To capture the *STDERR* stream you need to [redirect it by `2>&1`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), meaning that handle `2` (*STDERR*) is redirected where handle `1` points to (*STDOUT*). To ensure that the redirection is not applied to the `for /F` command itself, you need to [properly escape it (`^`)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in order for the special characters `>` and `&` to lose their particular meaning until the whole `for /F` command line was processed. The command to be captured eventually contains the redirection expression in an unescaped manner.