# Java 8 is installed, but java -version shows 1.4

Tags: java, scala

OS - Windows 7 64 Bit

I am getting "Exception in thread main", when I type `scala` in command prompt

[image: UnsupportedClassVersionError]

In Stackoverflow (already asked question) someone suggested to use same JRE and JDK version. So I uninstalled all the java (JRE and JDK) and installed JRE and JDK 8.

But when I check the `java -version` it says "1.4" and the I still get the exception(Exception in thread)

[image: java -version]

In Path, there is no java 1.4:

> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\client

In Control Panel -> Java -> Java tab -> view still says 1.8

[image]

How can I make scala work?

Comment: This isn't the `class path`, this is where the executables are. Try simple search for `java.exe` on your drive(s). There should be a 1.4 installation anywhere. And consider special installations of Java on Windows platforms. You may find a java.exe in the `Windows` folder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063831/what-is-the-difference-between-system32-java-exe-and-program-files-java-jdk1).

Comment: @learningKid , instead of adding photos, you can right click in cmd > Mark > select with the mouse what you want > right click (to copy) ... then paste it here > select the block and press Ctrl + K. This is how those who have the same problem will easily find your question.

Comment: Did you open a **new console** when you tried to run `java -version`?

Comment: that's  the trick  :) @engineer. I am stupid  ... opened in a new console. it Worked  Sorry Friends..

Comment: Ok, you can post the solution for your own answer and then accept it. But, please, use a nice formatting. Make it readable.

Comment: sure.. thank you ..you are awesome  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"open a new console"  then try java -version  .

Worked for me . Scala issue also resolved :) Thanks... @engineer